# Get the object clicked from the child component in React

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'd like to trigger the function handleDisplayProduct on click and pass to it the object clicked. So far it calls the function handleDisplayProduct when the list is generated for all the objects but the function is not triggered on the click event. 
So how do i bind the event onclick with the Container and passing to it the element clicked?

**Container**

```
// Method to retrieve state from Stores
function getAllProductState(){
 return {
  products: ProductStore.getProducts(),
 };
}

export default class ProductAllContainer extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
 this.state = getAllProductState();
}

handleDisplayProduct(data){
 console.log(data);
 // ProductActions.selectProduct(data)
}

render(){
 const products = this.state.products;
 return(
  <div>
    { products.map(function(product,i){
      return  (
        <ProductThumbnail
          product = { product }
          key = { i }
          **onDisplayProduct = { this.handleDisplayProduct(product) }**
        />
      )
    },this)}
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

**View**

```
const ProductThumbnail = (props)=>{

 return(
  <div>
   <LinksTo to="/" **onClick={props.onDisplayProduct}**>
     <h1>{props.product.headline}</h1>
     <img src={props.product.images[0].imagesUrls.entry[1].url} alt="Thumbnail small pic"/>
   </LinksTo>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the event listener to the react class. You can do it this  way.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = getAllProductState();
  this.handleDisplayProduct = this.handleDisplayProduct.bind(this);
}
```

or alternatively using es6, you can use an arrow function instead.

```
handleDisplayProduct = (data) => {
 console.log(data);
 // ProductActions.selectProduct(data)
}
```

Note: Class properties are not yet part of current JavaScript standard. So the second example wouldn't work unless you add a `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` babel plugin

Edit: Also @ryanjduffy pointed out a crucial mistake in your code. Refer his comment.

Comment: To add to this, you can't use `onDisplayProduct = { this.handleDisplayProduct(product) }` to pass the handler since you'll be passing the result of calling `this.handleDisplayProduct` instead of the function itself. Instead, I'd suggest that `<ProductThumbnail />` provides the handler payload instead of binding it here.

`const handler = function () { props.onDisplayProduct(props.product) }`

Comment: @ryanduffy - I have added onClick={props.onDisplayProduct(props.product)} on the <ProductThumbnail /> component instead...if it is what you meant. it still does the same : retrieving all the objects when the list of items is generated but nothing on the click event..i've added the bind(this) as suggested by deadfish

Comment: @ryanduffy - ok i've finally made it work following your suggestion using const handler